# How to use SignalR for autorefresh like data

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I've been looking into using `SignalR` for a while now, and I think I have a good candidate for it.

I have a page which allows users of the system to leave `Comments`, and at the moment it uses `JQuery` to periodically refresh the list of comments. I think `SignalR` would replace this nicely, i.e. if there were two users looking at the list and one wrote a comment, I would like it to appear instantly in the second.

All well and good, I have a *sort of* template where this works.

*However*

My system itself can sometimes add automatic notifications to the list - These are put into the database directly by a non-web based application.

How can I get `SignalR` to see the new information from the database and send it to the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SignalR` the [hub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) is a static part in your application. You can spin up a [System.Threading.Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer) in your webapplication to periodically check your database for new notifications and add those to the data used by the `hub`.

This can even be improved by using a [SqlCacheDependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642848/performance-questions-for-sql-cache-dependency).

A subjective side note: *I do agree this type of functionality is a very good candidate for `SignalR`*.

Comment: What about this scenario on [Refreshing data periodically using SignalR rather than broadcasting to clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899276/refreshing-data-periodically-using-signalr-rather-than-broadcasting-to-clients)? Any help please?