# periodically sending messages to all clients using signalr

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to send some data from server to all connected clients using hubs after a specific interval. How can I accomplish this using signalr hubs.

Comment: Have you looked at the SignalR.Sample NuGet package?  It does this.  We plan to publish a tutorial on the ASP.NET site about it in the next week or two.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just add

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

in your send Method.

Ex:

```
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        //call the broadcast message to upadate the clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message); 
    }
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

The following code renders the current time for every 5 seconds.

Here is script for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start();
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.  
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        //Appending the responce from the server to the discussion id
        chat.client.currentTime = function (time) {
            $('#discussion').append("<br/>" + time + "<br/>");
        };

        // Start the connection. 
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            //Call the server side method for every 5 seconds
            setInterval(function () {
                var date = new Date();
                chat.client.currentTime(date.toString());
            }, 5000);
        });

    }); 
</script>

<div id="discussion"></div>
```

And on the HubClass write the following:

```
public class ChatHub: Hub
   {
        public void currentTime(string date)
        {
            Clients.All.broadCastTime(date);
        }
   }
```

Comment: I don't want to delay the sending of message. Rather i want to send them some message periodically. Say after each 5 seconds i want to send them current date time.

Comment: @Ibrahim Use timer. Either from c# or jquery ajax function using setinterval.

Comment: how would i use the timer from server side (c#). just the small example. I know how to use from client side.

Comment: @Ibrahim you should use setInterval for that purpose. I'll edit my post in couple of minutes to give you the code for running periodically

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the original question - OP wants to broadcast updates from the server to connected clients on a server side timer (not pushed from other clients or simply delayed with a thread.sleep).

Answer (score 6):

Spin up the [System.Threading.Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14569167/55209), and from it's callback broadcast the message using specific hub.

Global.asax:

```
private Timer timer;
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs("~/signalr2");
        timer = new Timer(TimerCallback(timerCallback), null, Timeout.Infinite, 1000);
    }
}
```

Check the “Broadcasting over a Hub from outside of a Hub” section in [SignalR wiki page](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs).

Comment: I tried it this way too. But its still not working. For double checking i added 

var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Chat>();
            context.Clients.All.PublishMessage(nick, message);

in sendmessage method of simple chat application. But it doesn't work.

Comment: context.Clients.All.PublishMessage removing the All from this worked for me.

Comment: @Ibrahim i removing the All worked for you then you need to update SignalR. You're using a really old version and we're released about 6 more since then.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ReactiveExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and then setup an [Observable.Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228911%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) call. Then reactive will automatically call the lambda which can broadcast to your clients.

Answer (score 1):

I have stumbled upon this post by Jason Roberts => http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Using-Server-Side-Timers-and-SignalR-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx

He uses IRegisteredObject and HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject then a [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the class that does the work, I haven't tried it myself, but it looks exactly the sort of thing.